# Change MSI log location to network share for GPO deployments

Tags: windows, domain, group-policy, windows-installer

**TLDR: how do I set the equivalent of the /L*V "C:\package.log" msiexec cmdline option in a transforms file?**

I have an MSI I want to push to several computers in a domain. I'd like to look 
at the MSI installation log in each computer to make sure it installed properly.

I know normally Windows Installer leaves log files in %temp% named MSI.txt. However I'd like to have the logs in some central location so I can look at them carefully.

Is there a way to ask Windows Installer to put these logs into a folder on the network? Basically a way to say /L*V "C:\package.log" (which normally goes in the command line to msiexec) in a transform file I can set in the GPO?

There is a MsiLogLocation property but it's read-only, so nothing happens when I set it in Orca or in the command line to msiexec.